# What is wrong in my XPath?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xmldocument

Here I have the xml:

```
<root>
    <field ...>offer</field>
    <field type="ferrari" ...>car</field>
    <field ...>company</field>
    <field ...>whatever</field>
</root>
```

and I want to know the «type» of the «car» by extracting the element. I thought something like this:

```
/root[field='car']/field (or /root[field='car'])
```

was enough, but when I tried to execute my C# code:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.InnerXml = "..."; // xml of above
XmlNode node = document.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("... xpath of above ...");
```

the object «node» it always contains the first child element «field» (the offer) and in the case of SelectNodes("... same xpath ...") returns all the elements «field» ignoring the condition.

What's the problem? The XPath is wrong?

Comment: Your xml seems backwards.  Shouldn't the type="car" and the value of the element be ferrari?

Comment: Well I had to do a parser on that kind of XML and I can't change the structure of it, because it's a customer's definition. But I agree with you a structure like this is a little bit malformed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/root/field[text()='car']/@type
```

Will bring back a node representing the attribute "type" of the element "field" whose text value is "car".  The value of this XmlNode will be "ferrari".

```
/root/field[text()='car']
```

Will bring back a node representing the element "field" (whose text value is "car"), which you could programmatically get at the type attribute:

```
XmlNode fieldNode = document.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(@"/root/field[text()='car']");
string type = fieldNode.Attributes["type"].Value;
//type == "ferrari"
```

Comment: thanks man! :) I didn't know I had to specify that the inner content must be turned to text!

BR!